# How to send PUT request to ModelViewSet without passing a primary key in the url?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am particularly interested in using [`ModelViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)
for solving the challenge of updating the logged in user's profile. I am using the following definition:

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets

class ProfileRetrieveUpdate(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserProfile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

By overriding `get_queryset`, I am able to get the expected behavior, i.e. when I access the endpoints (say `profile/`), I get the profile of the logged in user. However, if I have to update the profile, I can only access `PUT` by going to `profile/6/`. Is there a way I can get `ModelViewSet` to expose `PUT` at the same endpoint i.e. `profile/`?

Comment: You can do this with [django-rest-framework-bulk](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register `ModelViewSet` HTTP method under any path you want.

```
path(
    "profile",
    ProfileRetrieveUpdate.as_view(
        {"put": "partial_update", "get": "retrieve"}
    ),
    name="profile-retrieve-update",
)
```

You will have to adjust other things as well as you don't provide `pk`.
Instead of overriding `get_queryset` method you need to adjust `get_object` for your needs.

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404


class ProfileRetrieveUpdate(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        obj = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, user=self.request.user)
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Now if you `PUT profile/` it should work as expected.

Comment: Hmm, I still get `Expected view ProfileRetrieveUpdate to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.`